# Create a branch off of the merge-base of two branches in magit

Tags: magit, git

At work, if I am working on a bug fix, I sometimes want to base my hotfix branch off of the `merge-base` of our `master` and `develop` branches, because the branch will eventually be merged into both of these branches, and sometimes, they (`master` and `develop`) will have diverged. From the command line I would do this with:

```
git checkout `git merge-base master develop`
git checkout -b my-hotfix-branch
```

What I am wondering is, **is there a straightforward way to do this in `magit`**?

I don't fully understand some of the options in the branching popup, even after reading the documentation, and I am hesitant to experiment with my work repository. I know how to do the second command (checkout a new branch once I have checked out the `merge-base`, but I am not sure how to check out the `merge-base` itself).

Worse comes to worse, I assume everything will go fine if I run the command from the `magit-run-popup`, but I am curious if there is a better way. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to do that because the bug was introduced before the merge-base and you want to be able to merge the `hotfix` branch into both `master` and `develop` without having to merge one of these two branches into the other?

Comment: @tarsius, potentially, yes. Usually this will be unnecessary, and it is enough for me to base my fix off of `master` or even `develop`, but I was told that I should just do it this way to be on the safe side so that I don't need to worry about what state `master` and `develop` are in.

Comment: But that of course assumes that the bug was introduced before the merge-base, so "to be on the safe side" doesn't really seem to apply. I think doing it as it was suggested to you only makes sense if you actually intend to merge into both branches. Otherwise you just branch of the `hotfix` at some essentially random commit. Branching of the commit that introduced the bug might make more sense. But that might have been a long time.

Comment: I would suggest that you figure out upfront whether the `hotfix` has to be merged into both branches. If so, then branch of the merge-base (or possibly the commit which introduced the bug). Otherwise branch of `master` and then merge it back into that. If it later turn out that the fix is also needed in `develop` and you don't want to merge `master` to get it, then you could always just cherry-pick the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to do that. What I would do - assuming that both of these branches have at most a few dozen commits since the merge-base - is to manually move to the merge-base in some log and then type <kbd>b c</kbd>`hotfix`<kbd>RET</kbd>. A good log to start from you would get with <kbd>l b</kbd> (assuming `--graph` is enabled), and then you have to press <kbd>n</kbd> a "few" times.

Comment: @elethan is one of `master` or `origin/master` configured as `develop`s upstream? If so, then it probably wouldn't be to hard to implement a generalized command to do this sort of thing (but I don't think it should be added to Magit). If `develop`s upstream is `origin/develop`, then you should probably change that and instead set the push-remote to `origin`.

Comment: My current situation is that I am a junior dev in a team of basically 2 people, and am not in a position to make any changes or even to propose changes to our current git workflow - nor, do I know enough at this point to really be able to choose between one approach or another. I was just curious if there was a quick way to go right to the merge-base of two branches through magit, since this is the way I was told to do it by team member #2 (who is basically my boss). I am trying not to be a squeaky wheel at this point :)